# C++ use a linux library on a mac (elf64-x86-64 on x86_64-apple-darwin)

Tags: c++, x86-64, elf

I'm currently trying to compile a program on a Mac OS X (10.9) using a library initially compiled for Linux.

Is there a way to use this library? Here is the output of `objdump -f libmylib.a`:

```
Hour.o:       file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x0000000000000000


Menu.o:       file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x0000000000000000


Tools.o:      file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x0000000000000000
```

I know my current architecture is `x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0`, and I wonder if, with the appropriate compiler flags, there is a way to make this compile.

One more thing, here is the error when trying to compile:

```
g++  -L /Users/gustavemonod/Desktop/ -o Parking Mother.o Keyboard.o -lncurses -ltcl -lmylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/gustavemonod/lib/libmylib.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/gustavemonod/lib/libmylib.a
```

Comment: Can you recompile `mylib` for OS X?

Comment: It would take more than the right compiler flags and if you just want something that works there's likely easier ways (e.g., build the lib for os x). But it might be an interesting project. I think as part of llvm or lldb there's an object file reader/writer library that can load an object file (elf, mach-o, or coff) into a sort of generic representation, and you might then be able to get it to work to output an object file in of a different format.

Comment: @AlexReynolds No, unfortunately, I **cannot** recompile this library as I do not have access to the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses a library format called [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). Mac does not use ELF (instead, Mac uses a format called [Mach-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O)), so I suspect that's going to be very difficult (if not actually impossible). You *might* be able to make the [Linux Binary Compatibility](http://www5.us.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/linuxemu.html) from FreeBSD work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link ELF objects (or archives or shared libraries) with Mach-O. You can try using Agner Fog's [objconv](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) utility, to convert x86-64 ELF to x86-64 Mach-O, which use the same (ELF) calling conventions. I wouldn't recommend this approach if you can compile from source.